# In Visual Studio how can i delete this every time i make coding it always have a file copy

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

[enter image description here][1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysJS7.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysJS7.png
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysJS7.png

Comment: Never seen that before.  In the Help menu there is a "report a problem" option that will log an issue with VS support.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild?

Comment: yes nothing happen

Comment: Did this occur when you create a new project? If yes, try to repair the Visual Studio. If no, like jason said, you could report this issue with log.